# Adobe AIR : get user's video content on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have to develop an AIR app for a client, that reads the video folder content and can play any video in it.
It's quite easy with Android, I can read any folder on the phone/tablet, but on iOS it's not that easy. I can't use `applicationDirectory` because the client wants to put videos himself later in the videos folder on iPad. (But if you have a solution to put files in applicationDirectory with iTunes or else, please share !)

I know there are some ane's that read the cameraroll content, but they display a native pickup screen, while I just need a list of the files.

I tried to use `File.documentsDirectory` to access content, but got no luck. If you have any idea, thanks in advance !

Comment: If you have the user's permission to access the files and folders, you should be able to traverse the device filesystem starting with **/** (the root folder).

Comment: You'll need an ANE to list the video assets from the user's camera roll on iOS. We have this in development with our ANE (https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.CameraRollExtended) but that functionality is not available yet unfortunately.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know when it will be available ?
Btw, there are no user's permissions on iOS, it's only on Android. And I need this to work on iOS.

Comment: Ok I find a workaround : in my XML file I added `<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>` to the iPhone infoAdditions, so that I can access to app's documents through iTunes. I add files with iTunes, and I can read the content of the folder in AIR with `File.documentsDirectory.getDirectoryListing()`
Hope it will help someone else !

Comment: @key,  consider making an answer for your question to better help future users.  You can also accept your own answer.   The more details the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a workaround : in my XML application file I added `<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>` to the iPhone infoAdditions, so that I can access to app's documents through iTunes. I add files with iTunes, and I can read the content of the folder in AIR with `File.documentsDirectory.getDirectoryListing()`
Hope it will help someone else !